# What is the minimum amount of numbers needed to create a 4x4 Hidato with a unique solution?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, optimization

Goal of Hidato:

> Fill in a grid with a series of consecutive numbers that connect each other horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

So I have been working on figuring out the minimum number of clues needed for an $n\times m$ Hidato puzzle such that it had a unique solution. (up to the $8\times8$ case)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA1wq.png) is the table I have made which lists the lower bounds of clues needed for a Hidato puzzle of size $n\times m$ to have a unique solution:

[image]

I am currently trying to figure out the lower bounds for $4\times m$ Hidato puzzles where $m\in\mathbb N$ and $4\le m\le8$, and would like to know the minimum amount of clues needed for a $4\times4$ Hidato puzzle to have a unique solution.

I have managed to create one with [8 clues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkdbY.png)

> [image]

however I would like to know:

> Is 8 is truly the minimum needed, or is it possible to have a uniquely solvable 4x4 Hidato puzzle with 7 clues?

Comment: Is the solution unique? It looks there are two solutions where '6' and '16' could be swapped to get from one to the other.

Comment: @hexomino ah right my bad. If it were to be unique with 8 numbers, I would actually have to remove the 7 and then put in a 6. My bad.

Comment: Wait a sec, does that mean I have accidentally answered my own question? because then we could remove the 5 to get a 4x4 Hidato puzzle with a unique solution with only 7 clues?

Comment: I think your comment is correct, you can alter the diagram in this way to get a unique solution from 7 clues.

Comment: For $3\times3$, the minimum is $2$ (not $3$): \begin{matrix} . & . & . \\ . & . & 9 \\ 7 & . &. \\ \end{matrix}

Comment: @RobPratt Oh my, that's actually impressive! Good job on finding that!

Comment: For $3\times4$, the minimum is $2$ (not $4$): \begin{matrix}.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.\\.&.&11&6\\ \end{matrix}

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works for 3 x 7: \begin{array} {c} . & . & 16 & . & 5 & . & . \\ . & . & . & . & . & . & . \\ . & 18 & . & . & . & . & 3 \\ \end{array}

Comment: @Nitrodon Oh my, I did not think that that would be possible! But at least it is :)

Comment: For $3\times5$, the minimum is $3$ (not $6$): \begin{matrix}.&.&2&9&.\\.&.&11&.&.\\.&.&.&.&.\\\end{matrix}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Update: I think 3 is possible:

> [image: 3 soln]

Solving this is as follows:

> First, add the diagonals and the 8 is then forced.
>  [image: s1]
>  Next, there's only one way to connect the 12 and the 16 without creating an island:
>  [image: s2]
>  Next, there's a deadend, that must have a 1
>  [image: s3]
>  And you're done
>  [image: done]

---

I think 4 is possible. I believe this has a unique solution. (Oh, just saw that someone posted something similar)

> [image: 4 soln]

Comment: Both the 4-clue puzzle and 3-clue puzzle have a unique solution, good job!

Comment: We're trying for the minimum, right? Not specifically 7-clue.

Comment: Yes, we are trying for the minimum. 7 clues was just my proposed lower bound.

Comment: That solution with three is very nice. Good explanation +1

Answer (score 7):

Here is a 4x4 Hidato with 6 clues which I believe has a unique solution

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

> ```
> ..A4
> ....
> ....
> 1..7
>
> (A is 10)
> ```

For 3x4, what about this?

> ```
> 3..
> c..
> ..1
> ...
> ```

Comment: I have confirmed that both have a unique solution.