# New record for minimally clued 5x5 Hidato

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, optimization

CrSb0001 has been studying [the minimum number of clues to force a unique solution in Hidato](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/125841/71652) for variously sized boards. They came up with a [5x5 Hidato with 5 clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/125851/71652) but it was found that it has multiple solutions.

Goal of Hidato:

> Fill in a grid with a series of consecutive numbers that connect each other horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

I was able to find a 5x5 Hidato puzzle with **just 4 clues** having a unique solution. This was verified with [a Picat program](http://retina.inf.ufsc.br/cgi-bin/picat.py?code=import+sat.%0D%0Ainstance%28A%29+%3D%3E%0D%0A++A+%3D+%7B%7B_%2C_%2C_%2C_%7D%2C%0D%0A+++++++%7B16%2C_%2C_%2C_%7D%2C%0D%0A%09+++%7B_%2C_%2C_%2C_%7D%2C%0D%0A%09+++%7B_%2C_%2C_%2C12%7D%7D.%0D%0Amain+%3D%3E%0D%0A++instance%28Puzzle%29%2C%0D%0A++hidato%28Puzzle%29%2C%0D%0A++Sols+%3D+solve_all%28%5Bff%2C+%24limit%285%29%5D%2CPuzzle%29%2C%0D%0A++printf%28%22Solution+found%3A%22%29%2C%0D%0A++foreach%28Sol+in+Sols%29%0D%0A++++printf%28%22%5Cn%22%29%2C%0D%0A++++foreach%28Row+in+Sol%29%0D%0A++++++writeln%28Row%29%0D%0A++++end%2C%0D%0A++end%2C%0D%0A++printf%28%22Number+of+solutions%3A+%22%29%2C%0D%0A++N+%3D+length%28Sols%29%2C%0D%0A++if+N+%3E%3D+5+then%0D%0A++++printf%28%225%2B%5Cn%22%29%0D%0A++else%0D%0A++++writeln%28N%29%0D%0A++end.%0D%0A++%0D%0Ahidato%28Puzzle%29+%3D%3E%0D%0A++R+%3D+length%28Puzzle%29%2C%0D%0A++C+%3D+length%28Puzzle%5B1%5D%29%2C%0D%0A++Puzzle+%3A%3A+1..R*C%2C%0D%0A++%25+all+numbers+are+distinct%0D%0A++all_different%28%5BPuzzle%5BRi%2C+Ci%5D+%3A+Ri+in+1..R%2C+Ci+in+1..C%5D%29%2C%0D%0A++Ri+%3D+new_array%28R*C%29%2C%0D%0A++Ci+%3D+new_array%28R*C%29%2C%0D%0A++foreach%28X+in+1..R*C%29+matrix_element%28Puzzle%2C+Ri%5BX%5D%2C+Ci%5BX%5D%2C+X%29+end%2C%0D%0A++%25+for+each+number%2C+next+number+is+adjacent%0D%0A++foreach%28X+in+1..R*C-1%29%0D%0A++++-1+%23%3C%3D+Ri%5BX%2B1%5D+-+Ri%5BX%5D%2C+Ri%5BX%2B1%5D+-+Ri%5BX%5D+%23%3C%3D+1%2C%0D%0A++++-1+%23%3C%3D+Ci%5BX%2B1%5D+-+Ci%5BX%5D%2C+Ci%5BX%2B1%5D+-+Ci%5BX%5D+%23%3C%3D+1%0D%0A++end.) (the instance is replaced with a 4x4 one to avoid spoilers; you're free to experiment with the program). Can you find one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
>      .  .  .  5  .
>      .  .  .  .  .
>      .  .  7  .  .
>      2  . 19  .  .
>      .  .  .  .  .
> ```

with verified unique solution

> ```
>     11 10  9  5 25
>     12  8  4  6 24
>     13  3  7 18 23
>      2 14 19 17 22
>      1 15 16 20 21
> ```

Comment: This is solvable by hand.

Answer (score 12):

It can actually be done with 3:

> ```
>      .  .  .  6  .
>      .  .  .  . 13
>      .  .  .  .  .
>      9  .  .  .  .
>      .  .  .  .  .
> ```

with verified unique solution

> ```
>      1  2  3  6  5
>     22 21  7  4 13
>     23  8 20 12 14
>      9 24 11 19 15
>     25 10 18 17 16
> ```

Comment: This is so good I forgive you for blatantly stealing my post layout ;-)

Comment: @loopywalt I don't know what you are talking about =-P

Comment: All 3 numbers 1 lower also seems to work

Comment: @Retudin the program linked in OP finds 3 solutions, then.

Comment: @Albert.Lang Just saw this, good job lol.

Comment: Great job! This is solvable by hand but very hard.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>      .  .  .  4  .
>      .  .  .  .  .
>      .  .  6  .  .
>      1  . 19  .  .
>      .  .  .  .  .
> ```

Also works as well as its mirror image

> ```
>      .  4  .  .  .
>      .  .  .  .  .
>      .  .  6  .  .
>      .  . 19  .  1
>      .  .  .  .  .
> ```

Both with unique solutions:

> ```
>      25   4   8   9  10
>      24   5   3   7  11
>      23  18   6   2  12
>      22  17  19  13   1
>      21  20  16  15  14
> ```

and

> ```
>      10   9   8   4  25
>      11   7   3   5  24
>      12   2   6  18  23
>       1  13  19  17  22
>      14  15  16  20  21
> ```

and in that logic there should be plenty more in a similar manner where mirror solutions also work. I haven't found any with 3 clues since (I think) you can't force a wall with a gap with only 3 if that makes sense. I'm unsure if the positions (where they are now) are vital to forming the wall with the gap though.

Comment: I would expect, given the nature of the puzzle, that horizontal _and_ vertical symmetries both always apply, no?

Comment: ... and rotations too. I would not consider those to be different puzzles/solutions.

Comment: True, both symmetries apply as well as rotations of solutions since the direction of execution would simply be mirrored/rotated as well. I don't mind taking the mirror "solution" away @JaapScherphuis I just figured people could still have those puzzles as "unique" too.

Comment: You also can reverse the numbers, i.e. apply n -> (26-n).  That would be less obvious.