# 5x5 Hidato with 4 single-digit clues

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Goal of Hidato:

> Fill in a grid with a series of consecutive numbers that connect each other horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

Yesterday I posted [New record for minimally clued 5x5 Hidato](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/125863/71652), asking for any 4-clue 5x5 Hidato with a unique solution.

However, none of the answers (or trivial transformations thereof) so far has an extra property my puzzle has: **all 4 clues are single digit numbers**, i.e. the four numbers given are between 1 and 9 inclusive. Can you find one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>      9  .  .  .  .
>      1  .  .  .  .
>      .  .  .  .  .
>      .  .  .  5  .
>      .  .  .  4  .
> ```

with verified unique solution

> ```
>      9  8 19 20 21
>      1 10  7 18 22
>     11  2 17  6 23
>     12 16  3  5 24
>     13 14 15  4 25
> ```

Comment: That was the exact puzzle I had, up to reflection.