# Minimally clued 4x5 Hidato (4 clues)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, no-computers

<sub>Puzzle attribution: Me
 :)</sub>

---

#### Background

---

So as you might or might not know, I have been [studying the minimum number of clues needed to force a unique solution in Hidato](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/125841/71652) for variously sized boards. I recently had come up with a [5x5 Hidato with 5 clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/125851/71652), although it was found to have multiple solutions.

Yesterday, [@Bubbler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/71652/bubbler) was able to find a [5x5 Hidato puzzle that had 4 clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125863/new-record-for-minimally-clued-5x5-hidato?noredirect=1&lq=1) while having a unique solution, and 14 hours ago, they also found a [5x5 Hidato puzzle with a unique solution and only single-digit clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/125881/5x5-hidato-with-4-single-digit-clues?noredirect=1&lq=1).

This morning, I managed to create a 4x5 Hidato puzzle again with 4 clues, which I verified to have a unique solution first by hand and then through [@Bubbler's Picat program](https://tinyurl.com/2s4hzh8p). Can you figure out the solution?

---

#### The puzzle

---

Goal of Hidato:

> Fill in a grid with a series of consecutive numbers that connect each other orthogonally or diagonally

To get the green checkmark $\color{green}✓$:

> Solve the following Hidato puzzle

[The puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqAxh.png):

[image]

Comment: Don't miss Albert.Lang's 3-clue 5x5. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/125886/30964

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>      1  17 10 9  8
>      16 2  18 11 7
>      15 3  12 19 6
>      14 13 4  5  20
> ```

> First, fill in the 19 (there is only one solution which reaches 16)
>
> ```
>      1  .  .  .  .
>      16 .  .  .  .
>      .  .  .  19 .
>      .  .  .  5  20
> ```

> Then, fill in the 18 and the 17 in order to avoid cutting apart the 1 and the 5 or hemming in the 16
>
> ```
>      1  17 .  .  .
>      16 .  18 .  .
>      .  .  .  19 .
>      .  .  .  5  20
> ```

> Then, we need the diagonal between 18 and 19 to give the 16 a path to escape, so we can fill in the 3 and the 4
>
> ```
>      1  17 .  .  .
>      16 2  18 .  .
>      .  3  .  19 .
>      .  .  4  5  20
> ```

> Using numbers with only one empty neighbor:
>
> ```
>      1  17 .  .  .
>      16 2  18 11 7
>      15 3  12 19 6
>      14 13 4  5  20
> ```

> There is obviously only one solution for the final three numbers.
>
> ```
>      1  17 10 9  8
>      16 2  18 11 7
>      15 3  12 19 6
>      14 13 4  5  20
> ```